# Map json Object with randomise array creation

Tags: javascript, java, json, angular, angular2-directives

I have JSON object and array

```
sampleJson={"id":1,"option1":"","option2":"","option3":""}
sampleArray=["car","","Animals"]
```

i want to add sampleArray to sampleJson in following format

```
sampleJson={"id":1,"option1"="car","option2":"Animals","option3":""}
```

sample array will be randomise like `["","car",""] Or ["","animal","Car"]?`

Comment: What is the order in which you want to assign `sampleArray` elements as `options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I found the solution

```js
var i=1;
    sampleData.forEach(element => {
      if(element.length != 0){
        sampleJson['option'+i]=element;
        i++;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sampleJson={"id":1,"option1":"","option2":"","option3":""}
var sampleArray=["car","","Animals"];
var count = 1;
sampleArray.forEach(function(ele){
    if(ele.length){
        sampleJson['option' + count] = ele;
        count++;
    }
})
console.log(sampleJson);//{id: 1, option1: "car", option2: "Animals", option3: ""}
```

Comment: in case of sampleArray=["","fruits","cars"] it shows sampleJson={"id":1,"option2":"fruits","option3":"car"}
i want it as
sampleJson={"id":1,"option1":"fruits","option2":"car","option":""}

Comment: How you are deciding the order in which you want values in options. For example how you decide that `option1` is `fruit` and `option2` is `car`

Comment: actually I am using two way binding in angular 2 for input box,
their are 3 input box we have provided in which at least 1 is mandatory in that case...if user entered sting in 2nd and 3rd text box at this situation i have to manage this json format...their will be any case

Comment: Hi @Ash, I have edited my answer according to your requirement. Please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sampleJson={"id":1,"option1":"","option2":"","option3":""}
var sampleArray=["car","","Animals"]
Object.keys(sampleJson).filter(function(k) {
    return k.includes('option');
}).forEach(function(k,i) {
    if (sampleArray.length > i) 
        sampleJson[k] = sampleArray[i];
});
console.log(sampleJson)
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: noo.. above code shows {"id":1,"option1":"","option2":"car","option3":"fruits"}
for sampleArray=["",car","fruits"] case...